# Coding/Running Java in MacBook Pro with Eclipse or NetBeans

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, osx-mavericks

I bought a new MacBook Pro which is MID 2012 and contains MacOSX 10.9.3.

Since I am a programmer, I have installed NetBeans with JDK 8.

However, today I opened NetBeans and wrote a piece of code just prints out "Hi" on screen.

The problem is, I got an error message which I have never seen before. It says that:

```
Unable to create the selected preference page.
Could not initialize class java.lang.UNIXProcess
```

both for Eclipse and NetBean.

I have tried googling and also tried to delete and reinstall all the files including JDK, however I could not came up with a solution.

Also, the another interesting thing is that when I run the Java code from terminal, I can compile and run perfectly, like:

```
Onur-MacBook-Pro:Desktop onursahindur$ javac Deneme.java
Onur-MacBook-Pro:Desktop onursahindur$ java Deneme
Hi
```

Below, the version of the SDK can be found from Terminal:

```
Onur-MacBook-Pro:Desktop onursahindur$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm not 100%, but isn't there an option within eclipse/netbeans to specify WHERE your JDK is installed? For Netbeans I think its under Tools > Java Platforms

Comment: In Eclipse the JRE is configured in Preferences > Java > Installed JREs.

Comment: actually I can show where the JDK is in Eclipse/NetBeans, but when I give the path of the JDK it does not see the library. I stuck on that issue :(